# Titanium app gives error about Swift flags when trying to run the project

Tags: ios, swift, titanium, titanium-sdk

I have a Titanium app for iOS. So far It was working ok, but suddenly it started giving me this errors:

> [ERROR] warning: conditional compilation flags do not have values in Swift; they are either present or absent (rather than 'DEPLOYTYPE=development')
> [ERROR] warning: conditional compilation flags do not have values in Swift; they are either present or absent (rather than '**LOG__ID**=e06779ed-4e79-4f3a-84d0-ab3d79067099')
> [ERROR] warning: conditional compilation flags do not have values in Swift; they are either present or absent (rather than 'DEBUG=1')
> [ERROR] warning: conditional compilation flags do not have values in Swift; they are either present or absent (rather than 'DISABLE_TI_LOG_SERVER=1')
> [ERROR] warning: conditional compilation flags do not have values in Swift; they are either present or absent (rather than 'TI_VERSION=12.1.2')
> [ERROR] ** BUILD FAILED **
> [ERROR] The following build commands failed:
> [ERROR]         Ld /Users/myuser/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/myProject/build/iphone/build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myProject.app/myProject normal (in target 'myProject' from project 'myProject')
> [ERROR] (1 failure)
> Process exited with 1

I have searched in my projects build folder in the .xcodeproj file for these flags and have found them. I have tried to edit them, but every time I try to run my project the file gets recompiled and the flags ar back again.

How can I solve that problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please build your app with `-l trace` and search for `errors generated` in those logs. The real error is above that block.

Did you update Xcode to 14.3?

In case you use iOS modules make sure they are up to date.

Comment: Using the trace the errour output gives the same errors. Ate leat the read lines are the same. And my xcode version is 14.2

Comment: The error at the end will be the same, that is correct. That error will appear for many issues (see https://github.com/tidev/titanium-sdk/pull/13881) but the real error is above that when you search for the `errors generated` part. In the example link it will be https://github.com/tidev/titanium-sdk/pull/13881#issuecomment-1635680256 . You could also upload the log so I can check.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if I can do it this way, but the link is to a file with my complete log. https://transfer.sapo.pt/downloads/1355d6a0-5f1a-4f0e-955f-44056412c503/sapotransfer-6008d700ebed8Pe/

Comment: lot's is missing in there, its just the last part of the log. But what version of Firebase (core and fcm) are you using?

Comment: Good evening, I tried to copy everything, but as it is a lot, many lines were deleted from the terminal. I tried to create a new file and copy the lines as they appeared.https://transfer.sapo.pt/downloads/fa8885f4-223d-4dd4-bbf4-d8254ff06a52/sapotransfer-600a2493a6a70Li/

Comment: The version of firebase.core is 8.0.0 and firebase.cloudmessaging is 1.1.0 and ti.admob is 6.1.0 (I don't know if it helps)

Comment: the FCM module is from 2018! Please update that and the other modules like imagefactory. And I'm not sure if you still need ti.cloud

Comment: Can you please tell me from where I can download all the modules updated? Or if there is any comand I can execute to update them?

Comment: at their github pages. e.g. https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-firebase-cloud-messaging and then the "Releases" tab. Check https://fromzerotoapp.com/use-modules-in-your-app/ for all places to find the ZIP files. There is no tool to up them. You just have to check the repos when you do an update of your app.

Comment: Good afternoon, I removed everything that had to do with FCM and it started working. Now I'm having another problem implementing Admob, but it has nothing to do with this error.

Thank you for your help

Comment: For that also make sure to check the latest PR https://github.com/tidev/ti.admob/pull/353 (zip included) and there is another recent one https://github.com/tidev/ti.admob/pull/354. 6.2.0 runs fine in a client app (simple banner view). So hopefully you can get it to work too